# Accessing lists from another Class in python

Tags: python, user-interface, optionmenu

I'm working on code for an assessment, parts at a time and I've made two classes so far. One of the classes holds all the information in lists, and the other class is for the visual part of a GUI. I want to have an option menu on this GUI and get the information for that option menu from one of the lists in the other class. How do I access a list from another class to put onto an option menu??

The code below is different to my assessment because I have to be careful about cheating etc. But all I really want to know is how to get those movie names into the option menu in the different class. PLEASE HELP!?

```
    from tkinter import * #used to develop GUI

    class Details: #name of class to store the lists 
            def __init__(self):
                    self.movie = ["The Hunger Games", "Catching Fire", "Mockingjay"]

    class GuiVisible: #class name
        def __init__(self, parent): #initilises instance variables
            issueLabel = Label(parent, text = "ISSUE", font = ("Arial", "10", "underline")).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = N) #label for that part of the GUI
            self.valuestr = DoubleVar()    

            labelName = Label(parent, text = "Name:", font = ("Arial", "9")).grid(row = 9, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
            self.variable1 = StringVar(parent)
            self.variable1 = self.Name.get()

            listMenu1 = OptionMenu(parent, self.variable1)            
            listMenu1.grid(row = 9, column = 5)        

    #main routine
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = Tk()
        interface = GuiVisible(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are trying to pull information from one class to another.

I made this quick example:.

```
class test1:
    array1 = ["The Hunger Games", "Catching Fire", "Mockingjay"]

class test2:
    for loop in range(len(test1.array1)):
        print(test1.array1[loop])
```

Class test1 defines the information then class test2 prints the information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps me understand a bit more thanks, but my code still doesn't work. I think it's because of the functions maybe and when I use the 'classname.listname' an error message always comes up with something like builtins.AttributeError: 'classname' object has no attribute 'listname'

Comment: Is that all of the code; or is it missing a bit? If so can I take a look at the rest; as it will help me better understand the problem :-)

Comment: It's missing a bit but all I need help with is above. Like if I typed in listMenu1 = OptionMenu(parent, OtherClassName.listName) I get error, I just want to know how to right the code correctly so I can get that list information in the option menu. Thanks for trying to help :)